# How do we analyse when given an order of a group, how many non-isomorphic group it has?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let a group has order say $m$ then we can prime decompose it. If it is of the form $pq$ where $p\leq q$ we have results by Cauchy. Also for group of order $2p$, we have some results, but I don't understand given any order by analyzing the order how can we conclude how many non-isomorphic group it has?

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://oeis.org/A000001 and references therein.

Comment: In general this is a very difficult (but well researched) problem, especially for powers of $2$.